# install jupyter server on aws using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter, aws-cloudformation

I am having some issues in configuring a Jupyter Server on AWS - Manually I am able to do this - however, I need to do this via Cloudformation scripts

The scripts work perfectly but they get stuck and the cfn-init hangs when they reach the code

```
service jupyter start
```

or

```
jupyter notebook
```

or

```
jupyter notebook &
```

the notebook gets started and I am able to log into the server - however, the cfn-init job does not complete - the control is not returned back to cfn-init to execute the next statement

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot cfn-init failures by looking at /var/log/cfn-init.log.
For more verbosity you can add '-v' to your userdata section that calls cfn-init. 
For example:

`"UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" :
  { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
     "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
     "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
     "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
     "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
     "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
     "         --configsets InstallAndRun ",
     "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
  ]]}
}`

Comment: Yes, I have done that and in my lines in metadata I am having the following

jupyter notebook &

and the command does not return back it is almost like I gave the command on the command line without &